# разница в обработке скриптов JS в браузерах

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, wordpress-плагины

Всем привет.
Установил плагин на сайт для покупки в один клик, сайт на WP, при нажатии долго грузится окно, я решил сделать видимую загрузку путем небольших манипуляциях в js-файлах плагина. Я добавил иконку загрузки, которая становится видимой сразу при нажатии на кнопку, и исчезает после события success
пример кода:

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.clickBuyButton', function (e) {
       jQuery('.overlay-loading').css('display', 'block');
        e.preventDefault();
        var zixnAjaxUrl = getAjaxUrl();
        var butObj = this;

        var urlpost = window.location.href;
        var productid = jQuery(butObj).attr('data-productid');

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: zixnAjaxUrl,
            async: false,
            data: {
                action: 'getViewForm',
                urlpost: urlpost,
                productid: productid
            },
            success: function (response) {
                jQuery('#formOrderOneClick').remove();
                jQuery(butObj).after(response);
                jQuery('.overlay-loading').css('display', 'none');
                jQuery('.popup, .overlay').css('opacity', '1');
                jQuery('.popup, .overlay').css('visibility', 'visible');



            }
        });
    });
```

В мозиле работает как надо, в хроме не срабатывает, т.е. срабатывает, если ставишь исключения в консоли, но вместе срабатывать отказывается.
вот сам сайт тут можно посмотреть [сайт](https://vinyllab.ru/product/%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82/)

Comment: Не работает, потому что стоит `async: false,`. Поменяйте на `true` и возможно получите еще больше непонятных ошибок!

Comment: да, заработало, ошибок вроде не появилось, спасибо тебе, добрый человече)